# My Chrome Extension makes chrome inspect window shut down by itself silently

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm writing a chrome extension that basically transfer response to my local server.

To run this code I just need to turn on the inspect window (so that I can get devtools work).

It runs perfectly for several hours but I find eventually it closes the inspect window, without any error or whatever log generated. The monitored site gives one response per hour and I just logged "OK" to the Chrome inspect console. I will see the count of OK grows to over 15k over hours but it will then make the inspect window closed. Chrome and the target website will stay alive forever.

Furthermore if I open inspect window again, my codes continue to work, for another several hours.

So maybe I run out of memory. How to prevent the inspect window shutdown? or at least how can I get a message that it is shutting down. And is there anyway to reopen it without manual operation?

Actually, inspect window won't shut down until it sends 10k responses. So if extension can close and reopen the inspect window should also make my codes run permanently.

BTW, Clear console logs doesn't stop the unexpected shut down.

Below are the codes I'm running.

```
chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(request => {
    request.getContent((body) => {
        if (request.request && request.request.url) {
            if (body.includes('SomeTag')) {

                var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var url = 'http://localhost:13345/testing';
                http.open('POST', url, true);

                http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'plain/text; charset="UTF-8');

                http.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                        chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval('console.log("' + http.responseText + '")');
                    }
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < request.response.headers.length; i++) {
                    if (request.response.headers[i].name == 'Date') {
                        http.send(request.response.headers[i].value + '\n' + body);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Sounds like a memory leak problem in your code so try [debugging it](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/) or a console log overflow problem in devtools so try not using it at all (do the output in your panel DOM) or use it less often.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that clearing the log doesn't help, but have you tried not logging at all?

I suspect that you may be running out of memory due to the use of `chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval(…)` as your logging mechanism. If disabling logging does solve the problem and you still want logging, you could adapt by using [message passing](https://developers.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to pass the message you want to log into a content script which will add it to the page's log.

Because I'm procrastinating at the moment, I took the liberty of converting your sample extension code into something that *should* work. I haven't tested this end-to-end so your mileage may vary.

```
// Copyright 2019 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

// manifest.json
{
  …
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "devtools_page": "devtools.html",
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content.js"]
  }]
}

// background.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(message => {
  if (message.name === "log") {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(message.tabId, message.value);
  }
});

// content.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(message => {
  console.log(message);
});

// devtools.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="devtools-loader.js"></script>

// devtools.js
chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(request => {
  request.getContent(responseBody => {
    if (request.request && request.request.url) {
      if (responseBody.includes('SomeTag')) {

        let body = '';
        for (let header of request.response.headers) {
          if (header.name === "Date") {
            body = `${header.value}\n${responseBody}`;
            break;
          }
        }

        const url = 'http://localhost:13345/testing';
        const config = {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'plain/text; charset="UTF-8"',
          },
          body
        };

        fetch(url, config)
          .then(response => response.text())
          .then(responseText => {
            const message = {
              name: 'log',
              tabId: chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.tabId,
              value: responseText,
            };

            chrome.runtime.sendMessage(chrome.runtime.id, message)
          });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: It did helps for extending the running time for another hours but still the inspector window will shut down, even if I turn off all the logs. And as I monitored the memory usage that mentioned by wOxxOm above, I see rises but GC bring memory to normal every minute.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that a clean chrome with no extension running, the inspect window will eventually leak out memory. Even if I stop recording for Network tab which is automatically turned on, I cannot stop the unexpected shutdown.

The webpage itself lives forever and taskmanager shows that only devtools tab's memory growing.

It's a stock monitoring web so it post/get some data every tick. I believe this is a chrome bug.